# Reload a Datagrid View returns Nothing

Tags: database, vb.net, datagrid

I have the a Function that loads data into from a Microsoft Access DB into a DGV  as shown in code below:

```
Public Sub LoaddgvCombined()  
    Try
        '//Clear DataGrid
        ds.Clear()
        dgvSales.DataSource = Nothing
        'dgvSales.Refresh()
        dgvSales.DataSource = ds

        '//Establish Connection to DB
        con.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource
        tables = ds.Tables
        con.Open()

        sql = "SELECT * FROM [tblINV_SalesRecord] WHERE CDate(adddate &  ' ' &addtime) < CDate('" & selectfrm & "')) ORDER BY temID ASC"

        da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
        da.Fill(ds, "tblINV_SalesRecord")
        con.Close()

        Dim view As New DataView(tables(0))
        source1.DataSource = view
        dgvSales.DataSource = view
        dgvSales.AllowUserToAddRows = False

        If dgvSales.RowCount < 1 Then
            MessageBox.Show("No Sales Recorded Found From " & selectfrm)
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message & " - " & ex.Source)
        MessageBox.Show("An Error Occured While Loading Sales Record ")
    End Try 
End Sub
```

It works fine the first time, but when I call the function the second time it empties the DGV but this time it does not load any Data.

Please can anyone point out what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing I noticed here is that you are passing to `tables` **BEFORE** you are getting the result of your query.

Try passing the values for `tables` after you fill `ds`.

Like this:

```
da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
da.Fill(ds, "tblINV_SalesRecord")
con.Close()
tables = ds.Tables '<=== transfer it here
```

It's showing empty because at the point you are passing to `tables`, your `ds` variable is not yet filled from your query.